# Difference between k-algebra isomorphism and k-extension isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am learning algebraic geometry. I know that $f\colon V \rightarrow W$ is an isomorphism of algebraic varieties if and only if $f^{*} \colon K[W] \rightarrow K[V] $ is an isomorphism of $K-$algebras.

I have found the following theorem: Let $f\colon V \dashrightarrow W$ a rational dominant map. $f$ is a birrational equivalence if and only if $f^*\colon K(W) \dashrightarrow K(V)$ is an isomorphism of $K-$extensions of $K$.

My question is, what is the difference between an isomorphism of $K-$algebras and an isomorphism of $K-$ extension of $K$?

Comment: It’s the same — a bijective $K$-linear ring homomorphism. Note, however, that it’s the *rings* which are different here: in the first definition, it’s the ring of *regular* functions on $V$; in the second definition, it’s the *field* of *rational* functions on the variety, ie the field of fractions of the ring of regular functions.

Comment: As an example, $K[x^2,x^3]\to K[x]$ (inclusion) gives an isomorphism of $K$-extensions, but not an isomorphism of $K$-algebras. The two rings have the same fraction field, you see.

Comment: @Mindlack You should probably mention that his first sentence is wrong without some more assumptions on $V$ and $W$ :P

Comment: @Alex Youcis: It probably depends on what the OP calls an algebraic variety. Does it have to be affine? Irreducible? Geometrically integral?

Comment: @Mindlack Should almost certainly be affine. Variety could mean irreducible or geometrically integral, but I've never heard it mean affine. This is contrast to their birational statement which doesn't need to assume affine.

Comment: Yes, Im thinking about affine varieties which are irreducibles.